# JDBC type Integer vs Ansi type Integer

Tags: sql, jdbc, sqldatatypes, ansi-sql

I am trying to get a better understanding of the intended meaning of `java.sql.Types`. Specifically for `Types.Integer` it seems to have two possible meanings. One is that it corresponds to the standard java Integer with a range from `-2^31` to `2 ^31-1`. Another (which seems to correspond to the ANSI sql standard) is that it is a number with a precision 10 and a scale of 0. The JDBC spec does not seem to define this.  Is there an actual precise definition of Types.Integer?